# How to incorporate subpreambles when including standalone TikZ images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I want to include a TikZ image into my document. I want it to be self-contained, so that I do not have to pollute my main document with all of its preambles. According to the [`standalone` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) (p. 22) it is possible to include these preambles with the `subpreambles` option. But when I set `subpreambles=true` I get an error and the preambles are ignored anyway. How can I incorporate the preambles of the TikZ code?

This is the code of my main document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
Text ...
\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone[subpreambles=true]{mytikz}
    \caption{My TikZ picture}
    \label{fig:tikz:my}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the code of my picture `mytikz.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{object_representation} = [
    align = center,
    draw = black,
    fill = white,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = 2cm,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm]
    \node (foo) [object_representation] {Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package xkeyval Warning: key `subpreambles' has been disabled on input line 7.

(mytikz.tex

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/object_representation' an
d I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18         \node (foo) [object_representation]
                                                 {Foo};
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone} % <--- option should be here

\begin{document}
Text ...
\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone{mytikz}
    \caption{My TikZ picture}
    \label{fig:tikz:my}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I would write your `mytikz` file shortly and with recent syntax for determining of the shape style:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}% <-- it is sufficient to has `tikz` only here
\tikzset{object_representation/.style = {% <---
    align = center,
    draw = black,
    fill = white,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = 2cm,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo) [object_representation] {Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for catching this!